# How to change the fallback font for missing languages?

Tags: fonts, language-support

The Arabic language in the new Ubuntu font is missing, so it has to fallback to the standard font, but the problem is that the standard font isn't good, and I want to replace it with Tahoma.

Is there a way to do that or it is built into the font itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<match target="font">
        <test name="lang" compare="contains">
                <string>ar</string>
        </test>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Tahoma</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

Stick that in your ~/.fonts.conf and everything written in Arabic should use Tahoma.

Comment: I'm glad I found this. I was looking for something similar. The XML file is still valid, however the `~/.fonts.conf` file is deprecated. Newer distros expect these conf files to reside in `~/.config/fontconfig/`

Comment: I confirm the `~/.config/fontconfig/` path works for me